# Some frenchb switches taken in account in \iflanguage conditional, but not all

Tags: babel, french

As shown by the following MWE, some `frenchb` switches (e.g. `\FBFrenchFootnotestrue`) are taken in account in (`babel`'s) `\iflanguage` conditional, but not all of them (e.g. `\FBStandardItemLabelsfalse`): the latter are taken in account only if directly inserted in the document body.

```
\documentclass[french,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
%
\newcommand{\test}[1][english]{%
  \selectlanguage{#1}
  \iflanguage{french}{
    \section{French}
    \FBStandardItemLabelsfalse%
    \FBFrenchFootnotestrue%
  }{
    \section{English}
    \FBStandardItemLabelstrue%
    \FBFrenchFootnotesfalse%
  }%
  Foo\footnote{Bar}.%
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \end{itemize}
}
%
\test
\test[french]
\test
\FBStandardItemLabelsfalse%
\test[french]
\end{document}
```

Do you know why and how to enforce all those switches to be taken in account in `\iflanguage` conditional?

Comment: My impression is that the conditional for “standard labels” has been kept out on purpose: lists should be uniform across a document, either French or “non French” style.

Comment: Indeed, `frenchb`'s doc claims "When French is not `babel`’s main language, `frenchb` does not alter the general layout of the document (even in parts where French is the current language): the layout of lists, footnotes, indentation of first paragraphs of sections are not customized by `frenchb`." (see page 2). But (1) by applying the switches of my MWE (okay, not mentioned in the user's doc), lists are not changed but footnotes are; (2) for separate articles gathered in a single document, each with its own language, I'd like them to be typeset with their corresponding layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly ask for the lists layouts to be updated to those specified by current switches by issuing

```
\update@frenchlists
```

This works either insider or outside the `\iflanguage`.
As the macro name contains the internal `@` character you will have enclose code using it with `\makeatletter...\makeother`

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[french,english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\test}[1][english]{%
  \selectlanguage{#1}
  \iflanguage{french}{%
    \section{French}
    \FBStandardItemLabelsfalse
    \FBFrenchFootnotestrue
  }{%
    \section{English}
    \FBStandardItemLabelstrue
    \FBFrenchFootnotesfalse
  }%
  \update@frenchlists
  Foo\footnote{Bar}.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Foo
  \item Bar
  \end{itemize}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\test
\test[french]
\test
\test[french]

\end{document}
```